# Deploying my MERN app to Heroku?

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, express, heroku, mern

I created an app that I want to upload on Heroku.

What I did so far is I change the listening port code:

```
  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
    console.log('Express server is up and running!');
  });
```

And then change the way mongoose connect:

```
mongoose.connect(
  process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/movies',
 {
   useMongoClient: true
 }
);
```

Then after that I created the heroku app and created the mLab MongoDB.

I then tried to push everything using `git push heroku master`.

Although the link refreshed it gave me this:

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

I don't understand on what to do next. Also I don't know how to seed localhost database from MongodB so I can use it on my heroku app.

Anyone here who can assist me? Thanks in advance! (Sorry newbie here)

Comment: Have you checked the logs, like the error message suggests doing? Without that it's difficult to guess what's wrong. Try running "*heroku logs"* after the failed deploy (this requires you have installed the heroku toolbelt).

Comment: You'll also want to include your Procfile and your package.json file, at least the scripts and the dependencies part. My uneducated guess is that you have a script that uses something declared as a devdependency while heroku runs npm install in production mode and don't get those installed.

Comment: Here's the log: https://anotepad.com/notes/62nne5

Comment: The error says *"Web process failed to bindto $PORT within 60 seconds of launch"*, meaning that the node server never started listening to `process.env.PORT` and Heroku eventually gave up waiting for it. Why it didn't start is difficult to tell from the log. Make sure you have a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) that tells Heroku how to properly start the server. It will default to just running *npm start* which often is used to start a webpack dev-server.

Comment: @ivami what can i put inside the procfile then? I use three things when i run my app locally: 'npm run webpack', 'nodemon server.js' and 'mongod'

Comment: Heroku will manage restarting your server if it falls over so you don't need to use nodemon. Your mongo database will also be handled by a heroku addon, so you won't need to start that yourself either. All you'll need to do is run web pack and a node command to start your server. Try `web: npm run webpack && npm start`, you'll then want to define the npm start command as `node server.js`.

Comment: I tried it but did not work out.